# Keras(TensorFlow) crashing and throwing ValueError

Tags: tensorflow, tf.keras

Im using Keras for regression however when I run the model I get 2 errors:

**1:**

```
E tensorflow/core/profiler/internal/gpu/cupti_tracer.cc:1329] function cupti_interface_-
>EnableCallback( 0 , subscriber_, CUPTI_CB_DOMAIN_DRIVER_API, cbid)
failed with error CUPTI could not be loaded or symbol could not be found.
```

**2:**

```
ValueError: slice index 0 of dimension 0 out of bounds. for 'sequential/gru/strided_slice_2' 
(op: 'StridedSlice') with input shapes: [0,?,279], [1], [1], [1] and with computed input 
tensors: input[1] = <0>, input[2] = <1>, input[3] = <1>.
```

1 takes place on the first Epoch, I believe it has something to do with the GPU not having the correct software

2 Occurs after having crashed when it is not able to find my checkpoint file, the file is not created due to all of the loss values being NaN values instead of a real value

*Full log (Apart from package errors to allow me to post):*

```
Train for 100 steps, validate on 1 samples
Epoch 1/20
2020-05-06 14:37:46.721382: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublas.so.10
2020-05-06 14:37:46.880683: I tensorflow/core/profiler/lib/profiler_session.cc:225] Profiler session started.
2020-05-06 14:37:46.880708: I tensorflow/core/profiler/internal/gpu/cupti_tracer.cc:1259] Profiler found 1 GPUs
2020-05-06 14:37:46.880871: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:55] Could not load dynamic library 'libcupti.so.10.1'; dlerror: libcupti.so.10.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2020-05-06 14:37:46.880880: E tensorflow/core/profiler/internal/gpu/cupti_tracer.cc:1307] function cupti_interface_->Subscribe( &subscriber_, (CUpti_CallbackFunc)ApiCallback, this)failed with error CUPTI could not be loaded or symbol could not be found.
2020-05-06 14:37:46.880885: E tensorflow/core/profiler/internal/gpu/cupti_tracer.cc:1346] function cupti_interface_->ActivityRegisterCallbacks( AllocCuptiActivityBuffer, FreeCuptiActivityBuffer)failed with error CUPTI could not be loaded or symbol could not be found.
  1/100 [..............................] - ETA: 2:00 - loss: nan2020-05-06 14:37:46.920527: E tensorflow/core/profiler/internal/gpu/cupti_tracer.cc:1329] function cupti_interface_->EnableCallback( 0 , subscriber_, CUPTI_CB_DOMAIN_DRIVER_API, cbid)failed with error CUPTI could not be loaded or symbol could not be found.
 99/100 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: nan  gpu/device_tracer.cc:88]  GpuTracer has collected 0 callback api events and 0 activity events.
100/100 [==============================] - 5s 52ms/step - loss: nan - val_loss: nan
Epoch 2/20
 99/100 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: nan
100/100 [==============================] - 4s 38ms/step - loss: nan - val_loss: nan
Epoch 3/20
 99/100 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: nan
100/100 [==============================] - 4s 38ms/step - loss: nan - val_loss: nan
Epoch 4/20
 99/100 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: nan
100/100 [==============================] - 4s 38ms/step - loss: nan - val_loss: nan
Epoch 5/20
 99/100 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: nan
100/100 [==============================] - 4s 38ms/step - loss: nan - val_loss: nan
Epoch 00005: early stopping
2020-05-06 14:38:06.066407: W tensorflow/core/kernels/data/generator_dataset_op.cc:103] Error occurred when finalizing GeneratorDataset iterator: Cancelled: Operation was cancelled
Error trying to load checkpoint.
Unable to open file (unable to open file: name = 'checkpoint.keras', errno = 2, error message = 'No such file or directory', flags = 0, o_flags = 0)
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/sample - loss: nan
loss (test-set): nan
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/matthew/PycharmProjects/pollution/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py", line 1619, in _create_c_op
    c_op = c_api.TF_FinishOperation(op_desc)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: slice index 0 of dimension 0 out of bounds. for 'sequential/gru/strided_slice_2' (op: 'StridedSlice') with input shapes: [0,?,279], [1], [1], [1] and with computed input tensors: input[1] = <0>, input[2] = <1>, input[3] = <1>.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "./manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/matthew/PycharmProjects/pollution/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/matthew/PycharmProjects/pollution/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/matthew/PycharmProjects/pollution/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/matthew/PycharmProjects/pollution/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 364, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/matthew/PycharmProjects/pollution/smog/management/commands/tensorflow_build.py", line 8, in handle
    build_model()
  File "/home/matthew/PycharmProjects/pollution/smog/business/tensorflow_building/building_tensorflow_model.py", line 372, in build_model
    plot_comparison(start_idx=100000, length=1000, train=True,x_train_scaled=x_train_scaled, x_test_scaled=x_test_scaled, y_train=y_train,y_test=y_test,y_scaler=y_scaler,model=model)
  File "/home/matthew/PycharmProjects/pollution/smog/business/tensorflow_building/building_tensorflow_model.py", line 134, in plot_comparison
    y_pred = model.predict(x)
  File "/home/matthew/PycharmProjects/pollution/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 1013, in predict
    use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing)
  File "/home/matthew/PycharmProjects/pollution/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py", line 1622, in _create_c_op
    raise ValueError(str(e))
ValueError: slice index 0 of dimension 0 out of bounds. for 'sequential/gru/strided_slice_2' (op: 'StridedSlice') with input shapes: [0,?,279], [1], [1], [1] and with computed input tensors: input[1] = <0>, input[2] = <1>, input[3] = <1>.
```

I cant find any other details on what could be causing this error online, any help is greatly appreciated as this is for a school project.

Comment: These are the logs, but we need to code to debug. Do you have a minimal reproducable example?

Comment: @FrederikBode Sorry, completely forgot to link the code: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jonem3/pollution/master/smog/business/tensorflow_building/building_tensorflow_model.py?token=ACZJ3I3UTXMFC6Y5ATFFKCS6WMCGM

Comment: I get a 404 not found error on this page. Is your `pollution` repo private?

Comment: @FrederikBode Try this: https://github.com/jonem3/StackOverflow.git

Comment: Is this a custom version of TensorFlow, or did you install via `pip or conda`?

Comment: pip installed: tensorboard==2.1.1
tensorflow==2.1.0
tensorflow-estimator==2.1.0
Keras-Applications==1.0.8
Keras-Preprocessing==1.1.0

Comment: Ive modified the code in the git repo so that its only the relevant code